# camera serial number in exif

Tags: camera, exif

I want to write camera serial number into a jpeg file.

based on exif standard that I got from here:

http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf

http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

camera serial number could be into two places:

Body serial number Id= 0xA431

Camera serial number id=0xc62f

but when I set them, and look at the image detail in windows, the camera serial number is blank.

How can I set the camera serial number?

What is the correct ID for camera serial number?

Comment: You might try another exif viewer, such as ExifTool or a browser plugin. There's other metadata standards, and the Windows tool might be reading the data from there. I believe ExifTool also shows the hex value of the tags, so you might use that to compare between your image and another image that you know it shows up with.

Comment: Windows Explorer reads camera serial number from XMP segment of jpeg file and it ignores Exif serial number value.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov Thanks for information. Interestingly, If I set the camera serial number in explorer, exiftools can read it, but if I set it via exiftools, Explorer can not read it. Is there any way that I can set xmp in c++?

Comment: Adobe has an [XMP SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html), it seems it's BSD licensed (to my surprise).